# How to create new comma-separated column from existing data?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have the following `account` table (MySQL RDBMS):

```
+----+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id |     username      | admin_for_blog | editor_for_blog | author_for_blog |
+----+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | author_only       | NULL           | NULL            | 1               |
|  2 | editor_and_author | NULL           | 2               | 2               |
|  3 | admin_only        | 3              | NULL            | NULL            |
+----+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

We are migrating to a role-based authorization, so we need to find the new roles for the above existing data. Roles are: `AUTHOR`, `EDITOR` and `ADMIN`. A user can be linked to multiple roles. Roles will be stored as comma-separated values (order doesn't matter). In the above data, the output should then be:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id |     username      | roles         | admin_for_blog | editor_for_blog | author_for_blog |
+----+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | author_only       | AUTHOR        | NULL           | NULL            | 1               |
|  2 | editor_and_author | AUTHOR,EDITOR | NULL           | 2               | 2               |
|  3 | admin_only        | ADMIN         | 3              | NULL            | NULL            |
+----+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

So basically:

- if `author_for_blog` is not null, then add role `AUTHOR`
- if `editor_for_blog` is not null, then add role `EDITOR`
- if `admin_for_blog` is not null, then add role `ADMIN`

Any hint on how to to this? I've been able to attach one role per user, but I can't find a way to manage multiple roles separated by commas:

```sql
select username,
    case admin_for_blog is not null when true then 'ADMIN' else
    case editor_for_blog is not null when true then 'EDITOR' else
    case author_for_blog is not null when true then 'AUTHOR' else
    'error!' end end end
from account
```

Comment: Why don't you use a normalized many to many relationship?

Comment: Storing values as CSV is very bad db design

Comment: It's not a good design.

Comment: @DanBracuk @Jens You mean having a `role (name of varchar, PK)` table and a `account_role (account_id FK, role_name FK)` table?

Comment: @sp00m yes that is a normalized design

Comment: Something like that, except I'd probably use a numeric PK.

Comment: Yes, but as these roles are mapped to a Java enum for now, I though it can be convenient to use CSV in DB and [map them transparently with Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373811/how-to-map-an-arraylist-of-primitives-to-a-single-column), so that roles are defined in one single place (in Java in this case). What do you think? A normalized DB would still be preferable in your opinion?

Comment: There are pros and cons to everything.  What you have to consider is all potential uses of the data, maintaining records as people come and go, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `concat_ws` which skips the `null` values.

```
select username,
concat_ws(','
         ,case when admin_for_blog is not null then 'ADMIN' end
         ,case when editor_for_blog is not null then 'EDITOR' end
         ,case when author_for_blog is not null then 'AUTHOR' end
         )
from account
```

Comment: I think this will give you somethink like 1,2,3 not ADMIN,AUTHOR,EDITOR

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the model I'll use, this actually answer my question perfectly, thanks!