# How do structure this query to combine two tables based on conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am brand new here, I read a lot but i didn't have an account until now, I wonder if someone would be kind enough to help me?

I have three tables:
Tasks
Users
Notes

Tasks and notes have a foreign key 'id' to the user table.
Notes has the foreign key 'id' from the task table.

These are the queries separately:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE taskid='id'

SELECT id, userid, taskid, nickname FROM notes WHERE taskid='id'
AND NOT userid='id' 

SELECT * FROM notes WHERE taskid='id' AND userid='id
```

What I want to do is combine this query into one, so that I end up with Tasks and offers that match the queries above in the same table.

I tried to inner join and union all but each select statement has a different number of columns, so I am a little stuck.

What I want to end up with is all tasks plus all notes for that task where the user is the owner of the task and the note. Plus all notes for the task where the user is not the owner(only a subset of the notes info) not all fields.

Thanks in advance, if you need more info ask.

Ok here is a spread sheet with a simple example of the result:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEPCyMLGKqd0ylafUvUVquUxcZ43V3sQFKYO3SjwIGo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you post sqlfiddle and expected output?

Comment: I will work on doing that.

Comment: I am using Postgres.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help as well.

Comment: How do you add ascii formatted tables into a post here? Its all out of line, i saw a nice one that scrolls horizontally on another post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471182/how-to-create-new-comma-separated-column-from-existing-data

Comment: I added a spreadsheet of the result.

Comment: I found the answer anyway, it was so simple, another guy suggested I should just null the fields of one of the tables. Simple but now the queries work!

Comment: "How do you add ascii formatted tables"? See the online help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting In a nutshell: select the text, then click on the `{}` button (the same way as you formatted the SQL code)

Comment: Thanks, it looks wrong in the preview, so I was scared to post it, the table was out of line, yet in the post I linked it looks nice and has a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer anyway, it was so simple, another guy suggested I should just null the fields of one of the tables in the query Simple but now the queries work!

Comment: I used a function in the database to combine all the queries into one.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing just `SELECT * FROM notes WHERE taskid='id' order by userid` and then doing the rest of processing in your programming language?

Comment: I am doing that currently but its a very slow to loop through all the tasks and then make more sql queries. I wanted to combine it into one query for speed and efficiency. This is for a rest api, so this query is taking a long time, doing it this way, I assumed that if I did it all in one sql query it would be faster.

Comment: if you really need more sql queries, then you didn't show all of them yet, did you?

Comment: All the queries are in the first post.

Comment: What is your programming language? All of this can be solved with this one query and no additional queries and some code in your programming language.

Comment: I use go, but I don't see how that is relevant,  I am asking what the sql queries are that I should use.

Comment: Well I told you what query to use. The results of that query contain all the data you have in the following two queries. Separating it out is a task for your programming language.

Comment: I already use the queries I posted above, but it requires looping though the results of the first query which I do not want to do. I want to combine all the queries into one query, not process the data in code and make multiple queries in a loop. I need the results of the task as well as the notes, so that query you posted is useless.

Comment: You could try: `SELECT 1,notes.* FROM notes WHERE taskid='id' AND userid='id' UNION ALL SELECT 2,notes.* FROM notes WHERE taskid='id' AND NOT userid='id'`. query one contains 1 and 2 at first argument, query 2 2, query 3 1,

Comment: Sure, but I only want all the fields from the notes, if the user is the owner of the note, i.e. the note has the userid as a foreign key, Other wise I want a subset of the notes fields and these notes are only the notes that are related to the task list that I grabbed at the start.

Comment: Coding isn't magic where you can make a wish and things start happening without any effort.

Comment: What? Why would you say that? Did I not make any effort? What wish did I make? The things you are suggesting are wrong. You don't seem to understand the problem, you are just telling me basic sql queries and telling me to do it in code, and now you are just being argumentative. If you don't know then don't post. I am trying to solve problems, I asked for help in a help forum, not a magical request. If its not possible to do this, then fine, but please don't tell me I am not making an effort and I am asking for magical thing....seriously.

Comment: You are refusing all routes to a solution. You don't want separate SQL statements, you don't want to code in Go and you don't want a UNION ALL solution in SQL either. I admit defeat by that attitude.

Comment: I am not refusing anything I posted at the start the sql queries I am already using. The Union will not work as I already said, because each query has a different amount of columns and the query is missing the tasks, which means you didn't understand the problem in the first place. I already have a solution coded in GO. That is not what I asked.  I asked how make the solution in sql only. You can admit defeat, but the fact is you do not even understand the problem, you failed to read it properly, and what you suggested is either wrong or I have already done and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I found the answer anyway, it was so simple, another guy suggested I should just null the fields of one of the tables. Simple but now the queries work!