# Hibernate: store List as JSON using @JsonSerialize and Converter: Basic attribute should not be a container

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an `@Entity` that has a `List<List<Integer>>` field:

```
@Entity
public class Game  {
  @Column
  List<List<Integer>> field;
}
```

I want to save it as JSON in  a database via Hibernate. 
I tried:

```
 @JsonSerialize(converter = FieldConverter.class)
 @JsonDeserialize(converter = FieldDeconverter.class)
 private List<List<Integer>> field;
```

```
@Converter
public class FieldConverter extends StdConverter<List<List<Integer>>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(List<List<Integer>> field)  {
        return "test-field";
    }
}
```

```
@Converter
public class FieldDeconverter extends StdConverter<String, List<List<Integer>>> {
    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> convert(String field)  {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I get `Basic attribute should not be a container` error.

I also tried this:

```
public class FieldConverter1 implements AttributeConverter<List<List<Integer>>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<List<Integer>> attribute) {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = FieldConverter1.class)
private List<List<Integer>> field;
```

but the error pesists:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map an ArrayList of primitives to a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373811/how-to-map-an-arraylist-of-primitives-to-a-single-column)

Comment: `I want to save it as JSON in a database` - What database do you use? What database type are you going to use for this column?

Comment: @itwasntme No, I still get `Basic attribute should not be a container` error

Comment: @SternK I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty strange issue if you've done the rest properly and tried restarting IDE and rebuilding the project.

I copied your FieldConverter1 class and created the same `field` in my entity and got no error, I'm assuming that wen you run your project it works smoothly even if IDE shows that error.

After doing some research, it appears to be known bug in some older versions of IntelliJ IDEA, but it's fixed in newer releases. It was mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207089995--Basic-attribute-type-should-not-be-Object-) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150816?_ga=2.246833604.15201531.1582923772-760503669.1574707723&_gac=1.19514058.1582594921.CjwKCAiAhc7yBRAdEiwAplGxX5kKaUfNLNAMNuwpqGbP1WgLsTPCqqISIHNYLfp-QZbCjOUo90M1XhoCH48QAvD_BwE).

If you can, try upgrading IntelliJ as it should fix that issue.
You could also disable/edit or suppress that inspection if you just want to get rid of that error:
[image: IntelliJ inspection options]
For example, disable inspection just for that field using this annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JpaAttributeTypeInspection")
```